# Help with CPU frequency management

Tags: 20.04, power-management, cpu, fan

I could use some help here. The fan on my laptop (HP pavilion cs0020ca) has been screaming loud since I tried to follow some power management wiki over here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower. I did everything except install the needed pieces of the power.d hook.
It all didn't work out to well so I rolled back all of the changes, however, I'm not sure what's stuck around because whenever my laptop is on AC Power, the CPU frequency throttles up to around 3GHz and that's what's causing the fan to scream. This is NOT what I want. I'd like my idle freq on power or battery to be low and only throttle up when needed (effectively utilizing the turbo boost more intelligently)

So even when I'm on AC power with the CPU governor set to powersave, it still throttles up. When I unplug the AC adapter, it slows down.

Anyone got any ideas how I fix this so that my CPU idle freq. is low even on AC power and only speeds up when needed?

On AC Power, `cpufreq-info` shows this:

```
nick@nick-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx:~$ cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.14 GHz.
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.06 GHz.
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.11 GHz.
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.30 GHz.
analyzing CPU 4:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 4
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 4
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.22 GHz.
analyzing CPU 5:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 5
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 5
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.06 GHz.
analyzing CPU 6:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 6
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 6
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.30 GHz.
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.29 GHz.
```

Answer (score 2):

I poked around my system and checked the the intel_pstate information and everything was set to powersave mode so I don't understand why the CPU was still turboing up to its max frequency on AC power.

However, I installed tlp and the problem seems to have resolved itself.

`sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw`

and

`sudo tlp start`